# Several lines in Plotly when using factor as variable for color of line

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have this plot in plotly.
[image: Plot without color]

When adding code:color = "code1" I get a plot like that shown below.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=800),
                     'value': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 800)})
## Add a column with the phase.
df['code1'] = np.repeat(['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF','ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF','ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF','ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF'], 50)
fig = px.line(df, x="date", y="value", color="code1",  template='plotly_white')
fig.add_scatter(x=df["date"], y=df["value"], line=dict(color="white"))
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.update_layout(title="day vs depth", xaxis_title="date", yaxis_title="depth")
fig.show()

## Solution
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=800),
    'value': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 800)
})

df['code1'] = np.repeat(['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF','ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF',
                         'ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF','ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF'], 50)

# Create a new column 'cycle' that increases by 1 each time 'code1' changes
df['cycle'] = (df['code1'] != df['code1'].shift()).cumsum()

# Combine 'code1' and 'cycle' into a new unique identifier
df['code_cycle'] = df['code1'] + '_' + df['cycle'].astype(str)

# Create a color map for your four unique labels
color_discrete_map = {'ABC': 'blue', 'BCD': 'green', 'CDE': 'red', 'DEF': 'purple'}

fig = px.line(df, x="date", y="value", color=df['code1'], line_group=df['code_cycle'], 
              color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map, template='plotly_white')

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") 
fig.update_layout(title="day vs depth", xaxis_title="date", yaxis_title="depth")
fig.update_traces(connectgaps=False)
fig.show()
```

[image: Plot with color]

It looks like I have a line for each variable in "CODE1". But I want just the same line as in the first plot but with different color for each variable in "CODE1". How to fix this?

Have gone thru plotlys documentation without finding any clear example.

**EDIT**
Code so it is possible to recreate this plot. it looks different, but problem with connecting lines is the same. Found the solution after some workaround.

Comment: any chance you could share some data? Your example isn't reproducible at the moment

Comment: Hi Mark. Did edit so it possible to recreate the problem.